# Trouble with data types after scraping a website with lxml and xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm scraping a website for data and end up pulling out numbers. The issue is when I try to perform logic functions in Python on the data it comes back as

```
class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'
```

My question is can I typecast this data somehow into a string or int so I can then do my logic statements?

Here is the code:

```
callType = item.xpath('.//span[contains(@id, "lblSignal")]')[0].text_content()

print callType
```

Here is the output:

```
76
```

When I try control statements on the data nothing happens. I think it's because I'm trying logic on incorrect types.

```
callType = item.xpath('.//span[contains(@id, "lblSignal")]')[0].text_content()
print type(callType)
print callType
```

This is my output:

```
<class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'>
76
```

So instead of trying to complete control statements with an "int", it is a different type. I've tried typecasting the variable but it remains that same datatype. Hope this helps...

Comment: without seeing the code it's hard to know where to start, however you can try returning __str__ on the data if what your seeing is an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xpath()` may return a list of `_ElementStringResult`s, not plain Python strings. The reason why you might sometimes wish to have `_ElementStringResult`s is that unlike `str`s they remember their parents (which they make accessible through the `getparent` method).

You could convert this to a string or integer by simply passing the object to `str` or `int`.

```
for span in item.xpath('.//span[contains(@id, "lblSignal")]'):
    callType = int(span.text_content())
```

Comment: callType = item.xpath('.//span[contains(@id, "lblSignal")]', smart_strings=False)[0].text_content() still returns that same data type... I'm guessing I have the syntax messed up.

Comment: The problem there is that `xpath` is returning `Elements`, not `_ElementSringResult`s. Unfortunately, the `text_content` method does not have a `smart_strings` parameter. So instead you'll just have to wrap the value with `str` or `int` yourself: `callType = int(item.xpath('.//span[contains(@id, "lblSignal")]')[0].text_content())`. Indeed, for integers, you'd have to wrap the value with `int` anyway.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks a ton for the info.  I'm brand new to lxml and xpath but it is pretty fun.  I truly appreciate the help.